# map animation on HTML5 canvas moving through the path when scrolling down page

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, canvas

I am new in HTML5 CANVAS. When I visiting this [website](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2016/05/yellowstone-national-parks-bears-video/) and this [website](https://tympanus.net/Development/StorytellingMap/), I was surprised at the fancy actions that when I scrolled down, the maps will keep going down and show  infos.

Consider of performance, I want to use Canvas instead of pure SVG. If i have a map SVG file with the path(with < path >), how can i achieve this effect? (path of the map moving while scrolling down the page)

What keywords can i search for or anyone can provide some direction
appreciate for any help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw pn SVG path to a canvas you need to use `Path2D`. In the next example I'm using an input type range to animate the stroke of the apple. You can use the scroll event.

```js
// get the path's data
var svgPathApple= ap.getAttribute("d");
// get the path's length
let paths_length = ap.getTotalLength();

// initiate the canvas
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cw = c.width = 500;
var ch = c.height = 500;
// create a new canvas path using Path2D
var theApple = new Path2D(svgPathApple);


ctx.lineDashOffset = -paths_length;
ctx.setLineDash([paths_length]);
ctx.stroke(theApple);
// use the input type range to change the lineDashOffset
ir.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  let v = ir.value;
  ctx.lineDashOffset = v;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.stroke(theApple);
})
```

```css
canvas,svg {
  border:1px solid
}

svg{display:none}
```

```html
<p><input id="ir" type="range" min="-909.682" value="-909.682" max="0" /></p>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 500">
  <path id="ap" d="M376.349,171.58 c0,0-37.276,22.484-36.094,60.946s31.438,61.577,42.012,63.313c4.127,0.678-24.314,57.988-42.039,72.189 s-36.067,17.159-64.47,5.917c-28.403-11.242-48.521,0.724-65.089,6.871s-36.687-0.361-63.905-39.415 s-57.396-129.585-15.976-173.964s87.574-26.627,100-20.71s34.32,5.325,59.172-5.917S363.922,153.237,376.349,171.58z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

These animations are both using a trick where they conditionally draw the number of path points of the trail depending on how far down the page or section you are. The following code illustrates this (much simpler than what they do), where scrollAmount would be determined by how far you are through a section.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// 0-1.0 for how far you have scrolled through a section
var scrollAmount = 0.5; 

var trailPath = [ [0,0], [10,10], .. many points .., [20,10] ];
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.moveTo(trailPath[0][0],trailPath[0][1]);

// only draw line until the point we are at, using floor to get us to an integer    
for(var i=0; i < Math.floor(scrollAmount * trailPath.length); i++){
   ctx.lineTo(trailPath[i][0],trailPath[i][1]); 
}
ctx.stroke();
```

The second referenced page is parsing and extracting the path from an SVG file loaded via Ajax, using a querySelector, and turning that into a list of points to iterate through. It does quite a bit more, but the basic mechanic of rendering the path is as above.